# Why Resource Server has to know client_id in Spring OAuth2?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing OAuth2 authorization using Spring Boot. I have already Authorization Server and Resource Server, now I want to access resources from Resource Server using `client_credentials` grant type.

I'm little confused about it, because in Resource Server I have to add `client_id` and `client_secret`. But why Resource Server really need it?

As I understand this concept client should get from Authorization Server using client credentials his access token. And then send this access token to Resource Server without any client credentials.

So why Resource Server also need some client credentials? Resource Server and client are two separeted entities, I don't understand why Resource Server has to know about `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Why access token is not enough to authenticate? `check_token` endpoint can return list of resources that can be accessed with this token and if client has this token, this means that he is already authenticated with client credentials to get this token.

What if I want to access from multiple different clients to this Resource Server?

Resource Server config:

```java
@Configuration
@RestController
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)  {
        resources
            .resourceId("translate-service");
    }
}
```

Resource server properties:

```
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8090/user
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=http://localhost:8090/oauth/check_token
security.oauth2.client.client-id=XXXX
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=XXXX
```

If I wont set client properties Spring will log warning:

> Null Client ID or Client Secret detected. Endpoint that requires authentication will reject request with 401 error.

And authentication will not work.

Maybe I doing something wrong and there is some solution to not provide `client_id` in Resource Server?

Answer (score 6):

If you use [`RemoteTokenServices`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/RemoteTokenServices.html) your Resource Server is also an additional client of the Authorization Server, see [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

> An alternative is the `RemoteTokenServices` which is a Spring OAuth features (not part of the spec) allowing Resource Servers to decode tokens through an HTTP resource on the Authorization Server (`/oauth/check_token`). `RemoteTokenServices` are convenient if there is not a huge volume of traffic in the Resource Servers (every request has to be verified with the Authorization Server), or if you can afford to cache the results. To use the `/oauth/check_token` endpoint you need to expose it by changing its access rule (default is "denyAll()") in the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`, e.g.
>
> ```java
> @Override
> public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
>     oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')").checkTokenAccess(
>         "hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
> }
> ```
>
> In this example we are configuring both the `/oauth/check_token` endpoint and the `/oauth/token_key` endpoint (so trusted resources can obtain the public key for JWT verification). These two endpoints are protected by HTTP Basic authentication using client credentials.

and [OAuth2 Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-resource-server-token-info):

> **2.4 How to Configure the Token Info Endpoint**
>
> The token info endpoint, also sometimes called the introspection endpoint, likely requires some kind of client authentication, either Basic or Bearer. Generally speaking, the bearer token in the `SecurityContext` won’t suffice since that is tied to the user. Instead, you’ll need to specify credentials that represent this client, like so:
>
> ```
> spring:
>   security:
>     oauth2:
>       client:
>         clientId: client-id
>         clientSecret: client-secret
>       resource:
>         tokenInfoUri: https://issuer/oauth2/check_token
> ```
>
> By default, this will use Basic authentication, using the configured credentials, to authenticate against the token info endpoint.