# Spring Security 5.2.1 OAuth2 with XING not working

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have set up OAuth2 with Spring Security for my localhost test application with

- Azure
- Facebook
- GitHub
- Google

Now I tried to do the same with Xing https://dev.xing.com/docs/authentication (OAuth2).

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          xing:
            authorization-uri: https://api.xing.com/auth/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://api.xing.com/auth/oauth2/token
        registration:
          xing:
            client-id: ${XING_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${XING_CLIENT_SECRET}
            client-name: Xing
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
```

Looks similar to the Facebook configuration.

After the login in the 4 step from the XING Documentation an error is thrown: `[invalid_client] Invalid client id and/or client secret.`

Using debugger I found out, that client id and secret are not added to that Authorization Request, not even when requesting GitHub. Now I wonder because I thought this is essential in this step.

DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java Line 75:

[image: Request to GitHub]

[image: Request to Xing]

In my understanding, Client ID and Secret would have to be used for all OAuth2 providers at this point, right?

Regardless, do I need to override the DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient class somehow, or is there an easy way to implement a solution for XING here?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55552788/5675325) Nabor?